# Delay epic action depending on payload

Tags: angular, angular-redux

According to the [documentation](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/Epics.html) it is quite simple to delay an action within an observable:

```
const pingEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType('PING')
    .delay(1000) // Asynchronously wait 1000ms then continue
    .mapTo({ type: 'PONG' });
```

But I'd like to delay the action depending on some value within the action payload. for example something like this (what doesn't work):

```
const pingEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType('PING')
    .delay(action => action.payload.delayTime) // Asynchronously wait the time defined within the action then continue
    .mapTo({ type: 'PONG' });
```

Unfortunately `.delay()` only takes a simple static value and I don't know how to set the value from the action. Someone any idea?

### Why do I need it?

The reason behind this behaviour is, that I'm calling a REST API within my epic, which creates a new item in the backend. When this call returns I'm going to trigger two action (through flatMap). One succeeded action to let the reducer update the corresponding state and a second action to get a list of all available items within the backend. Unfortunately is the backend a little bit slower (and I have no control over it), so that an immediate get call for all items returns a list without the freshly created item. Doing the same call 500ms later returns anything as expected. Cause this "get the whole list request" is exactly the same as it is when the page is shown the first time, I don't like to have this delay by all requests, but only when it is triggered after a create call. So my idea was to add a delay parameter to the action (which default value is zero) which will then be taken into account from the epic.

If nobody can tell me how to get the delay from the action, the second possibility would be to use a different action where another epic simply listens and use some kind of hard-coded delay, but it would be cool if I could parametrize this through the same action.

Comment: Actually i do not get your point put from my understanding you need to pass dynamic delay value to the parameter, so according to the git hub code of rxjs it's said it can take (date time, integer) or subscription delay. please follow the bellow link. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/delay.md

Comment: @Nour: Yes, delay() takes a parameter, but you cannot set it from the payload within the current action. You have to define it globally and not on a per action basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [`delayWhen`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/delaywhen.html), but it's a bit clunky (it works similar to `takeUntil`):

```
const pingEpic = action$ => action$.ofType('PING')
  .delayWhen(({ payload: { delayTime }}) => Observable.timer(delayTime)) 
  .mapTo({ type: 'PONG' });
```

So `delayWhen` delays your original `Observable` until the returned `Observable` by the callback function emits something. Then it resumes the ORIGINAL `Observable`, so if you had a `map` instead of a `mapTo` after, you could map on the original action/payload/whatever.

Comment: But the delay time doesn't come from another observable. Instead the desired value is already available within the original action and as far as I understand `DelayWhen` uses a second observable which I don't have.

Comment: @Oliver I know, that's why I create a timer observable there which emits it's first item after `delayTime` (as per my understanding this is the delay you need), so your original observable can continue after.

Comment: Ah, okay, seems I understand now. Will check this next week.

Comment: @Oliver that's why I added that it's a bit clunky... :( A reader of the code will have to go through the same process to understand why you are doing this.